# Функция chop() в C

Tags: c

Какой файл нужно подключить, чтобы можно было использовать chop функцию в C программе.
На данный момент компилятор выдает:

> `pinger.c:(.text+0x5ac): undefined reference to 'chop'`.

Comment: Если нужна такая функция в С, то придется самому ручками писать.

Comment: А в каком header-е ее объявление?

Answer (score 1):

undefined reference - это ошибка линковщика. Видимо, вы используете функцию из библиотеки, которая не линкуется к конечному коду. Надо библиотеку, в которой эта функция реализована подключить.

Answer (score 1):

А разве есть такая  функция в стандартных библиотеках С? Мне кажется, что нет. И гугление это показало.

Comment: У меня получилось chop найти только в Перле с полтычка.

Comment: Ну в PHP с ней тоже нет никаких проблем :D